# После выполнения подгрузки контента средством Ajax, необходимо его выровнять функцией js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

### Скрипт Ajax Jquerry загружает контент с другой страницы:

```
<script>      
    $(function() {

     var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
     var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
     var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
     $('#content').load(toLoad)
     } 
     });

     $('#nav li a').click(function(){

     var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
     $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
     $('#load').remove();
     $('#wrap').append('<span id="load">Загрузка...</span>');
     $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
     window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
     function loadContent() {
     $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
     }
     function showNewContent() {
     $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
     }
     function hideLoader() {
     $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
     }     
     return false;

     });          
    });   

    </script>
```

**После контент надо выровнять на JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = false;
    $(document).ready(function rovno(){
        if ($('body').width() <= 800) {
                isMobile = true;
            }
            if (!isMobile) {
        $('.container').each(function(){
            var highestBox = 0;
            $('.uslugi-top', this).each(function(){
                if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
                    highestBox = $(this).height();
                }
            });
            $('.uslugi-top', this).height(highestBox);
        });
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Непонимаю.. как после загрузки контента Ajax'ом, запустить функцию выравнивания "rovno"

Comment: Читаю информацию про Success. Но ни как не пойму как его применить

Answer (score 0):

**Эх было стыдно не понять((( проблема решена, спасибо за внимание!**

```
 <script>      
        $(function() {

         var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
         var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
         var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
         $('#content').load(toLoad)
         } 
         });

         $('#nav li a').click(function(){

         var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
         $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
         $('#load').remove();
         $('#wrap').append('<span id="load">Загрузка...</span>');
         $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
         window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
         function loadContent() {
         $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
         }
         function showNewContent() {
         $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
         }
         function hideLoader() {
         $('#load').fadeOut('normal',rovnya());
         }
         function rovnya(){
            var isMobile = false;
        $(document).ready(function rovno(){
            if ($('body').width() <= 800) {
                    isMobile = true;
                }
                if (!isMobile) {
            $('.container').each(function(){
                var highestBox = 0;
                $('.uslugi-top', this).each(function(){
                    if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
                        highestBox = $(this).height();
                    }
                });
                $('.uslugi-top', this).height(highestBox);
            });
        }
        });
         } 
         return false;

         });          
        });   

        </script>
```